# In BBEdit, how can I search for a pattern and then copy all the lines found with that pattern?

Tags: bbedit

In BBEdit (11.6.9), using find with grep checked on I'm looking for lines in a large file containing this pattern:

```
registeredTd="11/\d\d/2017
```

It stands for a registered date of November, 2017 in my file.

If I "find all" I get correctly see 69 occurrences of the pattern in the file i the results window.

But how, then, can I copy those found lines?

I can copy the results of the results window itself, but that copy (1) contains extra junk at the beginning and most importantly (2) does not contain the complete line. The lines in the result window are truncated.

Is there a way of copying all the complete lines containing the pattern?

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, the answer to this was to use the Text > Process Lines Containing... menu. There you can enter the same `registeredTd="11/\d\d/2017` search parameter, and there is a checkbox option to copy the lines with the search results. It works perfectly.

Comment: BBEdit is so good...  I needed to find and copy all lines containing say ABC and used the above with: ^ABC(.?)*.